# Updating elements of a csr matrix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, sparse-matrix

X_Train is a sparse 22000x97000 matrix in csr format and i want to update all elements in some columns.

If i do this by a for loop, it takes so much time:

```
for i in range(0,21999):
    for x in range(0,75):
      val = X_Train[i,x]
      val = val + 15
      X_Train[i,x] = val
```

How can i do it in much simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) to do this, if you aren't already using it.

You can construct a second sparse matrix tmp, where tmp[i, j] == 15 for each element you want to update. Then you can change your operation to a csr_matrix + csr_matrix, which is quite fast!

Comment: Good way. But then again: how is it possible to create such a csr_matrix whose specified column values are equal to a certain value?

Comment: Create a dense matrix, convert to sparse, and then resize...  

`block = 15 * np.ones((22000, 75))
to_add = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(block)  
to_add.resize((22000, 97000))  
X_Train += to_add`

Also, you'll want to use xrange instead of range- xrange is a generator, so only one value will be stored in memory at a time. range creates and stores a 22000 length list in memory in this case.

Comment: to_add.resize((22000, 97000)) function gives the error "AttributeError: resize not found". I tried it to do from np arrays and sparse matrices but couldnt make it.

Comment: My mistake, you want "reshape" not "resize." You should read the documentation, though.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The function is implemented for lil matrices, do that then convert.